# Deploy .Net Core Web API on cPanel

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, cpanel

I have an Angular application, with backend in .Net Core API. I have deployed the Angular part successfully on cPanel. But I don't know how to deploy the API on cPanel, as it doesn't have any HTML file. I just want to run the .dll file. Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Check with your `cPanel provider` if they suppport `Asp.net web API` In addition, if they have [`Kestrel web server`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-6.0) integrated within it.

Comment: Can you please share the complete deployment guide